# Spring @CachePut to put the same value with two keys

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I'm using `Spring` with build-in cache using `@Cacheable` and `@CachePut` annotations.

I have 2 methods in my @Service, one to save value in database, second to get value from database. Both of them uses cache.

```
@CachePut(key = "#code")
MyObject saveMyObject(MyObject o, String code) {
    return dao.save(o);
}

@Cacheable(key = "#code")
MyObject getMyObject(String code) {
    return dao.getMyObject(code);
}
```

While saving object I would like to put it in another cache e.g.

```
@CachePut(key = "'TMP_'.concat(#code)")
```

but I can't use two `@CachePut` annotations on `saveMyObject` method.

What should I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use org.springframework.cache.annotation.Caching annotation to group your CachePut:

```
@Caching( put = {
        @CachePut(key = "#code"),
        @CachePut(key = "'TMP_'.concat(#code)")
})
MyObject saveMyObject(MyObject o, String code) {
    return dao.save(o);
}
```

Comment: awesome, didn't know about Caching annotation!

Comment: `@CachePut(key = "'TMP_' + #code")` is valid shorter syntax. Not sure which one is better